# What system component is responsible for rendering text in android?

Tags: android, project

Right to left languages are not rendered correctly in my android device -- letters are not connected and sometimes reversed. I wanna fix this, but I don't know where to start. What system component is actually responsible for this?

Answer (score -1):

There is something called the Font Engine Manager which does the work of reading the True Type Font (.ttf) Files (it contains an engine called layout/shaping engine which is responsible for rendering the text properly), 
I think the following links would be useful: [1](http://behdad.org/text/), [2](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/OpenType%20Dev/arabic/intro.mspx)